# Is it possible to use puree in a siphon whip?

Tags: puree

does someone have experience with putting puree in a siphon whip, to achieve a fluffier texture? Does it work?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can; you can do both sweet and savory foams.

I never did it (I don't have a siphon), but from what I can feel when eating foam/espuma is that the input purée needs to be quite fine; blend/purée and then pass through a fine mesh sieve.

Just google "foam espuma recipe" and you will find a lot of recipes.

Comment: And if you *don't* to this step, you risk the siphon getting clogged ... which means you have to unscrew the top of it, which can be bad.  (my mom had to do it once when she used fresh ground nutmeg in a recipe he had for spiced whipped cream ... at first they were just scrapping it off as it leaked out, but then one it was unscrewed far enough, I was told it made a real mess.  (she was at a dinner party at a friend's house, so I didn't see it))